# Stop Wordpress "Auto Drafts" from showing?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to query a custom post type. Despite being set to "post_status = publish" it is still showing blank "auto draft" pages on the front end, though I cannot locate them on backend. How do I get rid of these posts?

```
<?php
    global $themeple_config;

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
        'post_status'   => 'plublish',
        'orderby'       => 'post_date',
        'order'         => 'DESC'
    ) );
```

Comment: I think you see draft posts as long as you are logged in as admin.

Comment: @yuyokk I see them on front-end whether logged in or not.

Comment: and if it is your real code, you have a typo in a 'publish' word

Answer (score 1):

It was simply a typo. "`plublish`" should have been "`publish`" obviously.

Correct code is as follows:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
) );
```

Credit to @yuyokk for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

see the following code if it can help you.

```
global $wpdb;

if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) ) return;

if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) return;

$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_status' => 'publish' ), array( 'ID' => $post->ID ) );

clean_post_cache( $post->ID );

$old_status = $post->post_status;
$post->post_status = 'publish';
wp_transition_post_status( 'publish', $old_status, $post );
```

for more information click [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)